# Overriding appsettings.json in IIS

Tags: iis, .net-core

I have a .net core web project which I'm publishing to IIS on Windows (10 or Server). I cannot seem to get IIS to provide the connection string through the Configuration Editor. I want the connection strings here so that it's not overwritten after every deploy.

I have tried using `ASPNETCORE_ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection` and `ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection` but neither do the job I always get a 500 error stating that the connection string cannot be null.

What am I missing here?

Here's part of my `Startup.cs` file: Note that this application was in a time before the default config did this for you.

```
 public class Startup
 {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddUserSecrets<Startup>()
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }
}
```

## Edit:

I've setup a brand new .Net Core 2.2 app. Even with the newer program/startup. The connection string doesn't come through.

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) //<-- adds config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-3.0#prefixes

Comment: @LexLi I already read that and as you can see from my question I've tried `ASPNETCORE_` which is supposed to work OTB. The link you provide is talking about a custom prefix.

Comment: Can you create a small reproducible app that replicates your issue and upload to Github? You could for example be missing the call to .AddEnvironmentVariables() etc

Comment: @MindingData I updated the question. I forgot to mention that I do have `.AddEnvironmentVariables()`. I'll create a simple web app and post to github

Comment: Can you try removing the ASPNETCORE_ part? I'm looking at the config provider https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/d469707ab18eef7ed0002f00175a9ad5b0f36250/src/Config.EnvironmentVariables/EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider.cs And tracing from the CreateDefaultBuilder, it doesn't pass a "prefix" into it, so I don't think you should be using the ASPNETCORE bit.

Comment: @MindingData haza! Please turn your comment into an answer so I can give you some points

Comment: Oooo internet points! Done :) Happy to help. Can't believe how good having the source code is for this stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to remove the ASPNETCORE_ prefix from your Environment variable (Just your connection string not the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT).

I'm looking at the Microsoft source code here for the Environment Variables Configuration Provider : https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/d469707ab18eef7ed0002f00175a9ad5b0f36250/src/Config.EnvironmentVariables/EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider.cs

And it does take a "prefix" if you want it do, but when I look at the source code for "CreateDefaultBuilder" : https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L177

It just calls it with an empty prefix param, meaning that you shouldn't use any prefix at all :

```
config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

You can ofcourse manually add the call to AddEnvironmentVariables with a prefix of your choosing that you can then prepend to your environment variables too

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can't believe I didn't think to go read the source. Most of what I found on the subject was talking about Azure and several articles made it sound like it required the prefix. Some times it just takes the a fresh pair of eyes I guess.